# Shortcut for closing panel windows on OS X

Tags: macos

Is there a keyboard shortcut to close the windows with the tiny stoplight buttons that sometimes pop up in Mac OS X e.g. for help menus etc?

I hate when I open one of those tiny windows by accident, hit cmd-W, and then either nothing happens or I accidentally close the actual window I was looking at instead of the useless window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape usually does it for Panels (Windows that have the smaller control buttons).  Its really up to the developer though, they can change/override those shortcuts (like iCal's panels typically require you to use Cmd-W), even inadvertently, but generally just hitting Escape will nix them.

The other thing, if they're "Inspectors," as has become the prevalent term for them throughout OS X, the shortcut key used to call them is typically able to dismiss them as well.  See the CMD-ALT-I inspector in Finder, Cmd-I Inspector in Preview, etc.

There is generally a rhyme/reason to these (but again, not always, its up to the developer). If the inspector doesn't pull focus from the parent window (ie. if the inspector's buttons are red, but so are those on the window that owns them) use Escape.  If the Inspector's buttons are lit up, but the parent Window's are dimmed, i.e. in iCal, then the panel is being treated as a full window.

Comment: I can't believe I never thought to try Escape! *smacks forehead*. Perfect. Thanks!!